# JQuery Autocomplete Select Function Only Completes One Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using a jquery autocomplete function to grab items from a database and replace fields. Using the select function and some AJAX it replaces the current info with the needed info. 
However, I need it to run twice, and the autocomplete seems to only run the last line in the select function:

```
 $(document).ready(function($){
    $('#client_name').autocomplete({
    source:'suggest_client.php', 
    minLength:2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#client_name").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $("#client_nameID").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
        var clientValue = ui.item.value;
        getAjax(clientValue, 'client_replace', 'client_info.php?client_id=', "");
        getAjax(clientValue, 'client_contact_div', 'get_contact.php?client_key=', "");
        return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Code for getAjax:

```
function getAjax(seek, getId, destUrl, reset) {
    if (seek=="") {
        document.getElementById(getId).innerHTML=reset;
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(getId).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",destUrl+seek,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling this is a problem with the `getAjax()` function. Can you post its source?

Comment: Added the code for getAjax(), it works for several other purposes, but I have not tried to call it twice as in the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `getAjax()` function. At the very beginning of the function, you need to declare the `xmlhttp` variable:

```
function getAjax(seek, getId, destUrl, reset) {
    var xmlhttp;
    /* ... */
}
```

#### Explanation

The problem is with variable scope. In the `getAjax()` function, you assign a value to the `xmlhttp` variable without declaring it first (using the `var` keyword). According to [MDN's documentation on the `var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed.

So every time `getAjax()` is called, you're assigning a value (the `XMLHttpRequest` or `ActiveXObject`) to `xmlhttp`, which -- since it's never declared -- is treated as a **global variable**. So when that second call to `getAjax()` runs in the last line of your `select` callback, it's overwriting the `xmlhttp` variable from the first call before that first request has a chance to complete.

If you declare the variable with `var xmlhttp` at the beginning of your function, then every call to `getAjax()` will have *its own instance* of the `xmlhttp` variable, preventing it from being treated as a global variable and overwritten.

Comment: Nailed it. I owe you a beer. Thank you very much.